# ios/core data - saving entity for a specific entity object

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data, nsuserdefaults

i got a qeustion about core data and the rules of relationships.

I have a entitie with multiple Users. The Users have a optional one-to-many relationship to a entitie called event. On my App start i create a User (I my self) and also other users and save them in CD. The Object of the User that **i m**, is also hold in NSUserDefaults.

So, now i created a event and want to assign it to my userobject entitie that is saved in core data. I thought to use the user object that i saved in the userdefaults and add the event to it, like here:

```
Event *event = (Event *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
//property setters
event.createdBy = userObjectFromNSUserDefaults;
```

Is this the right way? Will that assign the Event to that specific User (in that example me) ?

Another qeustion is:

My event class (subclass of nsmanagedobject) has also a NSSet property with add and remove methods that add/remove invitedUsers or acceptedUsers to that event. How do I use those methods right?

Any help gets a cookie :=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the first question - Yes, thats the way to make relationships in Core Data.
You just assign a specific object (NSManagmentObject, yes?) to a property.

The other way to day that, if it's one to many, is to do

```
[userObjectFromNSUserDefaults addEvent:event];
```

again, if its management object.

The only problem I see here, is that you save it in nsuserdefualts. That means that when you load it from there, it is not attached to you MOC, and I guess it won't work.
You need to save some id or something in the nsuserdefaults, not the object itself.
When the app loads, fetch that object from the db using that id.

Comment: i have written a class that creates and return a MOC. What if I use that MOC to add the Event? Would that work ? Anyway is it approbate to save a object in the userdefaults? first cookie earned :D

Comment: I'm not sure about saving an object in the userdefuals. I think it safer to save some id/string that can help you fetch the object when needed.